# how do I do ldap authentication with wget?

Tags: linux, wget, authentication, ldap

I'm trying to crawl an old Reviewboard server I own so I can create a static copy and archive it, and I'm doing this using wget per recommendations from a few people, using the recommended way of crawling and downloading a server like so:

```
wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --domains $DOMAIN --http-user $USERNAME  --ask-password $THE_SERVER
```

However, the server requires an LDAP authenticated login, so all I ever get is the login page and some related files. The same issue occurs if I just do `--user` rather than `--http-user`.

My question is can I do LDAP authentication with wget, and if so, how?

Since I'm sure these comments will come up:

1. I've made a JSON archive using rb-tools already, but would strongly prefer a static web copy.
2. I have the option of allowing anonymous read-only access because I'm an admin on the server, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1):

LDAP is not an authentication *mechanism* – it is merely an account *storage* backend; it's essentially the same as storing accounts in MySQL or such. Thus, there is no such thing as "LDAP authentication" as far as HTTP clients are concerned.

The actual mechanisms HTTP *has* are "Basic" or "Digest" for password-based logins, or "Negotiate" for Kerberos-based logins; the `--http-user` option would work if your website used one of those.

However, your website most likely uses a forms/cookies-based login page, which to HTTP clients is completely indistinguishable from a regular redirect to a regular webpage. Wget *will not* be able to automatically recognize and fill in those forms.

If that's the case, what you *could* do is log in via your regular web browser, then copy the necessary session cookies to wget's "cookie jar" file (or possibly pass them directly using `--header`). Then the website would recognize you as being logged in.

If you open "Developer Tools" → "Network" in Chrome or Firefox, each network request will have a "Copy as cURL" option which gives you a full `curl` command line. Find the specific `--header …` option which sends your session cookie, and give it to wget.